# DataContract where is a List add XML tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization

I have a problem when serializing an XML

These are two of my classes

```
namespace LiveLines.Core.Model.Pregames
{
    [DataContract(Name= "bestlinesports_line_feed")]
    public class PreGameLines
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "event")]
        public List<PreGameEvent> PreGameEvents { get; set; }
    }
}




namespace LiveLines.Core.Model.Pregames
{
    [DataContract(Name = "event")]
    public class PreGameEvent
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "event_datetimeGMT", Order = 0)]
        public DateTime Event_DateTimeGMT { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "sporttype", Order = 1)]
        public string SportType { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "scheduletext", Order = 2)]
        public string ScheduleText { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "league", Order = 3)]
        public string League { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "participant", Order = 4)]
        public List<PreGameParticipant> Participants { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "drawrotnum", Order = 5)]
        public int DrawRotNum { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "drawmoneyline", Order = 6)]
        public int DrawMoneyLine { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "drawTitle", Order = 7)]
        public string DrawTitle { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "period", Order = 8)]
        public PreGamePeriod Period { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I return the xml, the event tag appears as the parent of the event disstincts, when it should only show the events directly

that's how it's coming

[image: actual]

This is how it should be

[image: has to be]

Comment: Have you tried to remove DataMember attribute from PreGameEvents property in PreGameLines?

Comment: If I delete that data member, it does not show anything.

Comment: Then show your code to serialize